# want to press a key to stop my loop while the program is not selected c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm using a Windows Form Application, and I have a loop that counts to a specific iteration, via async for loop. I have a button to stop said loop, AND a keypress that can also stop the loop. The problem with the second one however, is that when the program is NOT the active window, it completely ignores any keystroke and keeps going.

I do not know how much of my code you would need, but heres the async part of it

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Start Button
        {
            stopLoop = false;
            cpsLabel.Text = 0.ToString();
            await Task.Delay(5000);//wait 5 seconds before clicking
            int speedSec = int.Parse(secondsBox.Text);
            int speedMil = int.Parse(millisecondsBox.Text);
            if (speedSec == 0 && speedMil == 0)
            {            }
            else
            {
                if (rightCheck.Checked == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i != int.Parse(iterations.Text) && !stopLoop; i++)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)//it should stop now
                            break;
                        DoRightMouseClick();
                        await Task.Delay((speedSec * 1000) + speedMil);

                    }
                }
                if (leftCheck.Checked == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i != int.Parse(iterations.Text) && !stopLoop; i++)
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)//it should stop now
                            break;
                        DoLeftMouseClick();
                        await Task.Delay((speedSec * 1000) + speedMil);
                    }
                }
            }
            cpsLabel.Text = 0.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your app will do, but anyway you can implement something similar with a key logger https://github.com/ibaydan/KeyLogger/blob/master/Program.cs be careful not to get in trouble. When a key is press (enter) stop the loop and store the username and password for user internet banking :p

Comment: It's more just to click my mouse buttons, nothing malicious lol. But I'll look into that

Comment: _"... is that when the program is NOT the active window, it completely ignores any keystroke and keeps going."_  Did you expect something else?

Comment: The whole idea with async is that you don't need `Application.DoEvents();`

Comment: Okay, never mind, that fixed it lol thank you :)